# User profile cannot be loaded, after creating new standard account

Tags: windows, windows-10, user-accounts, login, login-screen

I am trying to create a standard -not administrator- account on my Windows 10 PC. The account gets created but, when I try to sign-in, I get the error "The User Profile Service service failed the sign-in. Profile cannot be loaded".

I am not sure how it happened, but it happens every time I create a standard account. I have not tried with creating an Administrator account, but I believe that the problem may be related to me changing some folder permissions on the drive. The built-in Administrator account loaded just fine when I activated it, but I am not sure if this means that ANY administrator accounts are okay, since the built-in Administrator account is "special".

After trying to login using the new account and getting the error, the other profiles disappear and I cannot select them. Basically, I cannot use another profile to login because they are not on the logon screen. After restarting, I still get to the logon screen of the new profile.

I have tried using the recovery environment and loading the registry hives to change the last logged on account and the default account after power on, but I always get the new account to show up.

The only way to go back to using the other, working accounts is to do a System Restore.

How can I fix this?

Comment: What folder did you change permissions on, since you believe it’s relevant, you will now have to provide that information

Comment: New user accounts are built using a default user directory, at least partly. Messing with this will impact the creation of new accounts. It's not the only thing, but it's something to check. Also, doing a repair on your OS is a good thing to do. There's guides on checking for file corruption issues and repairing these online.

Comment: I have tried the repair multiple times. I have changed the permissions on the whole drive, drive except the Program FIles and Windows folders. I put my account as Owner and the only one with Full Permissions, deleted the rest, but I do not remember exactly.. Realising the mistake, I also gave Full Control to the System account.